# How is scaled_dot_product_attention meant to be used with cached keys/values in causal LM?

Tags: pytorch, language-model, self-attention

I'm implementing a transformer and I have everything working, including attention using the new `scaled_dot_product_attention` from PyTorch 2.0. I'll only be doing causal attention, however, so it seems like it makes sense to use the `is_causal=True` flag for efficiency. This also works as I'd expect as long as the k, v and q tensors have the same size.

But I'm not sure how to pass along past (cached) keys/values to the function in this mode. If the k, v tensors are wider than q, I need a rectangular mask as wide as k/v and as tall as q, with the upper *right* triangle masked out. All is well if I construct such a mask myself and pass it to the function. I get behavior similar to typical causal attention, where past tokens are attended to fully and new tokens (for which there are queries) are attended causally.

According to [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention.html), though, `is_causal=True` is equivalent to using a mask built with:

```
attn_mask = torch.ones(L, S, dtype=torch.bool).tril(diagonal=0)
```

Where L and S are the query and key/value lengths, respectively. This has all but the lower *left* triangular portion masked out, which attends partially to past tokens and not at all to new tokens. Is this causal mode just not suitable for my use case, or am I missing something?

Suppose I have the following tensors:

```
q = torch.rand((1, n_heads, 3, head_dim))
k = torch.rand((1, n_heads, 6, head_dim))
v = torch.rand((1, n_heads, 6, head_dim))

attn_output = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, attn_mask=None, is_causal=True)
```

Where k and v are wider since they're concatenated onto the cached results of a previous inference pass. `scaled_dot_product_attention` applies the following mask:

```
[[0, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf]
 [0,    0, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf]
 [0,    0,    0, -inf, -inf, -inf]]
```

But I would (maybe naively?) expect the attention operation to use a mask like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, -inf, -inf]
 [0, 0, 0, 0,    0, -inf]
 [0, 0, 0, 0,    0,    0]]
```

Can I achieve this somehow with `scaled_dot_product_attention`, or am I maybe going about this all wrong? How am I meant to use the function with a cache of past keys/values?